# NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED exception thrown from com.google.gwt.xhr.client.XMLHttpRequest

Tags: firefox, gwt, xmlhttprequest

I am developing an application using GWT in version 2.5.1.

Few days ago we found in our logs that there is a huge amount of exceptions (few per second!!!) that look as follows:

```
Nov 5, 2014 6:00:45 PM com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceUtil logOnServer
SEVERE: (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) : 
com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SerializableThrowable$ThrowableWithClassName: (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) : 
 at Unknown.ZHe(StackTraceCreator.java:174)
 at Unknown.WFe(StackTraceCreator.java:508)
 at Unknown.IHf(Exceptions.java:29)
 at Unknown.pIb(XMLHttpRequest.java:164)
 at Unknown.OMe(RequestBuilder.java:411)
 at Unknown.anonymous(XMLHttpRequest.java:351)
 at Unknown.gHe(Impl.java:189)
 at Unknown.jHe(Impl.java:243)
 at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:70)
```

At least in two cases the problem happened when the application was used from Mozilla Firefox web browser. To stop that, it was not enough to close the browser, but also to kill process from the Task Manager. But I am not sure if it couldn't be triggered also by another browser.

I also found this comment in the com.google.gwt.http.client.Request class, method cancel():

```
/*
 * There is a strange race condition that occurs on Mozilla when you cancel
 * a request while the response is coming in. It appears that in some cases
 * the onreadystatechange handler is still called after the handler function
 * has been deleted and during the call to XmlHttpRequest.abort(). So we
 * null the xmlHttpRequest here and that will prevent the
 * fireOnResponseReceived method from calling the callback function.
 * 
 * Setting the onreadystatechange handler to null gives us the correct
 * behavior in Mozilla but crashes IE. That is why we have chosen to fixed
 * this in Java by nulling out our reference to the XmlHttpRequest object.
 */
```

I don't have knowledge about how requests are working but I am wondering if new releases of Mozilla Firefox didn't cause that above solution doesn't work in some cases.

I would like to add also that the problem arises randomly and I couldn't reproduce it on demand.

Do you have an idea what is the source of the problem and could you please give us any advice how to solve this issue or maybe some workaround how to deal with it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It might be better to post this on GWT's bugtracker (ideally, with a minimal working example) - if this truly is a bug. But in order to do that - have you tried with the newest version of GWT? (2.7.0) Your bug might have already been fixed.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am not able to reproduce this bug. It happens irregularly from time to time. Additionaly, for the moment, I have no possibility to chnage the GWT version. Therefore I am looking for a solution or workaround for GWT 2.5.1.

Comment: Have you managed to find solution for this?
It has happened for me too, but only once.
Using GWT 2.7.0.

USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
EXCEPTION: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) : 
 at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated.$fillInStackTrace(StackTraceCreator.java:168)
 at com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException.JavaScriptException(JavaScriptException.java:106)
 at com.google.gwt.lang.Exceptions.caught(Exceptions.java:25)
 at ...

Comment: Unfortunately not. But after we've upgraded the GWT to version 2.6.1 the problem haven't appeared again to this day.